# pause playback for videoview in Recyclerview item when it is scrolled offscreen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I want to pause playback for a videoview inside the recyclerview when it is scrolled offscreen.

when the videoview is scrolled back and becomes fully visible, the video should resume playback from the same position.